# Change to Canadian (CDN) French number formatting in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, number-formatting, french, vba

I would like to build a piece of code which can convert numbers in my workbook from English to French number formatting.

For example,

- English formatting would be `$1,000,000.99`, and
- French would be `1 000 000,99 $`

I can not seem to find any default French codes built into excel and using a `,` instead of a `.` for the decimal does not show numbers less than $1.

Any assistance or advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the currency symbol appear to the right of your numbers, use the `NumberFormat` property of a `Range` object and set it to:

- For dollars: `#,##0.00 [$$-C0C]`
- For euro: `#,##0.00 [$€-C0C]`

The behavior of commas and periods for decimals and digit grouping is usually controlled by your Region and Language Settings in Windows.

You can change this setting application-wide (i.e. it will affect any workbook opened on your machine) by changing the values of `Application.DecimalSeparator` and `Application.ThousandsSeparator` in VBA. Alternatively, you can achieve the same effect by going to File > Options > Advanced and uncheck "Use system separators"

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have a loop of code which I am trying to use to find and replace all currency formatting in my workbook but it does not seem to replace with new formatting code properly.  

For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 [$$-40C]"
    Sheet.Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
 Next

It returns a application/object defined error. Any ideas?

Comment: @Greg usually that error relates to referring to an object that hasn't been `Set`. This is probably because you're using `Sheet` in the `For Each` loop. Try adding a `Dim Sht as Worksheet` just above the for and using `For Each Sht in ActiveWorkbook.Sheets` instead. You'll also need to change any `Sheet` inside the loop to `Sht`

Comment: I have `dim Sheet as Worksheet` written into my code and all following code uses this property however it will not run. The error occurs at `Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 [$$-40C]"`

Comment: @Greg my bad, the code should be `[$$-C0C]`. Try that instead. I've edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

To get the code for any action in Excel:

1. start recording a macro
2. do what you want to replicate via code
3. stop the recording
4. check the macro code (ALT+F11)

In this case applying the formatting gives this code:

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 $"
```

Hope this helps.