# Trying to get VBA to show figures in French Canadian Currency

Tags: excel, vba, currency, number-formatting

so $4,200.00
should appear as 4,200,00$ (Commas as the decimal point and $ on the right

This Code Generates 4,200.00$ (Almost perfect save for the Decimal)

> Columns("C:E").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 $"

but when I try to replace the decimal with `, or \,` it completely messes up
4,2,00 $

Comment: Not sure you can have the same character for both the thousands separator and the decimal separator - likely what's confusing Excel here. If I recall correctly the thousands separator would be a space in a fr-CA locale, no?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467694/change-to-canadian-cdn-french-number-formatting-in-excel-vba

Comment: I tried that too didn't seem to work application.DecimalSeparator = ","
    Application.ThousandsSeparator = "," preceeeding the number format

Comment: You can always store it as text:  `Range("C1").Value = Replace(Format( Range("C1").Value,"#,##0.00 [$$-C0C]"),".",",")` but that would require looping the range or using variant array and looping those.  And you would need to change the format of the cell to text.  And you end up with text and any formula that references those cells would need to convert it back to a number.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change to Canadian (CDN) French number formatting in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467694/change-to-canadian-cdn-french-number-formatting-in-excel-vba)

Comment: well the good news is I wouldn't have any formulas to worry about so I should be able to make that work (if that's the only way i'll work it out, still its disappointing that excel comes with a Date format (where its just a few characters of code) but nothing on Currency why much Quebec insist on being different

Comment: seems to do the same thing ends with Decimals, i'll probably either have to turn the whole thing into a text array and use replace or tell Quebec to get with the rest of the Country already

Comment: Again, the thousands and decimal separator characters are NOT the same in the _actual_ fr-CA locale; **you are trying to implement an ambiguous format** that simply doesn't (cannot) exist and that isn't used anywhere... and then blame it on Quebec being different. If your system is set to fr-CA locale, then Excel will appropriately format both date and currency values as per fr-CA specifications by default - that is, a space for the thousands separator, and a comma for the decimal separator (as shown in the two links above). Why not stick to fr-CA standard format?

Comment: okay so first im guessing you're from quebec and I offended you with the "get with the rest of the country comment" for that I apologize since it wasn't necessary, still think its a pain in the neck to have to chance the entire locale and then change it back since its for english and french documents

Answer (score 1):

okay I think I finally figured out a way to do it cleanly

my problem was in the other solutions I didn't understand how the decimal change worked(had to read the microsoft documentation)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.decimalseparator

and also turns out Quebec currency is actually 4 200,00$

so if anyone else is having this issue and like me didn't read the documentation heres the solution

also just for background my code has a string called Language_Code ('E' means English 'F' means French)

> If Language_Code = "F" Then
>
> ```
> Application.DecimalSeparator = ","
> Application.ThousandsSeparator = " "
> Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
>
> Columns("B:B").NumberFormat = "[$-040C]mmmm d, yyyy"
> Range("A6").NumberFormat = "[$-040C]mmmm d, yyyy"
> Columns("C:E").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 $"
>  Else
> Application.UseSystemSeparators = True
> Columns("B:B").NumberFormat = "mmmm d, yyyy"
> Range("A6").NumberFormat = "mmmm d, yyyy"
> Columns("C:E").Style = "Currency" End If
> ```